# Php executable not found in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm trying to add local PHP CLI Interpreter but PhpStorm doesn't find the executable when I try to add this in the PHP executable path.

I run `whereis php` in terminal and I get the good path (`/usr/bin/php`) but in PhpStorm It doesn't exit.

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: please run `php -v` and paste an unedited output. It's better to include it into your original question.

Comment: Voici le résultat de php -v: ``PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 (cli) (built: Feb 11 2020 15:55:52) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
``

Comment: The `7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.3` version is non-canonical/custom: IDE can't parse custom PHP versions unfortunately. I would advise to reinstall PHP so that it would have common/generic version format, e.g. `PHP 7.3.5 (cli)`